# Jquery loaded content with button not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, external

I am trying to have a button work inside a external html. I am using Jquery `.load('external.html #id-of-div');`.

I also have tried to simply place an `"alert("comments");"` inside the external file but it is never fired.

Here is my script for button to load external html: **(from internal main html)**

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
  $('#container').css({'display': 'block'});
  $('#container').load('external.html' #external-id-of-div);
});
```

Also from (from **internal** main html) a Script to call for a button inside the external html 'more-info'; this 'more-info' button is nested inside *#external-id-of-div*

```
$('.more-info').click(function(){
    if(toggle = 2) {
        $('.full-copy').slideDown(400, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('disappear');
        });
        console.log("one");
        return toggle = 1;
    }
});
$('.full-copy').click(function(){
    if(toggle = 1) {
        $(this).slideUp(500, function() { 
            $(this).addClass('disappear');
        });
        console.log("two");
        return toggle = 2;
    } 
});
```

The html is the following: (from **internal** main html)

```
<span id="button">Click to Load External Content</span>
<div id="container"></div>
```

The html is the following: (from **external** main html) **My Problem** I also have placed a `alert` tag which also is not fired when loaded from **internal** html but `alert` works fine if previewed as the **external** file individually.

```
<div id="external-id-of-div">
    <span class="more-info">Click to expand More INFO</span>
    <div class="full-copy disappear">
           LOREM IPSUM COPY>>>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Outside the jQuery ready");
        $(function() {
            alert("Inside the jQuery ready");
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.disappear { display: none; }
```

Not sure what is wrong...

I appreciate any answers that may help and thank you in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
load('external.html' #external-id-of-div);
```

should be

```
load('external.html #external-id-of-div');
```

And while you're using `.load()` you'll need to [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```
$(document).on('click','.more-info',function(){
// And
$(document).on('click','.full-copy',function(){
```